# Range - Change reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim Tgt As Range
    Set Tgt = Range("A1")
End Sub
```

I'd like to change the reference of Tgt which is currently "A1", I'd like to change just the column, not the line, but I don't want to set Range("XX") again.

Is there other way I can change the column of Tgt?

If I do Tgt.Column = 3, it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `Set Tgt = Range("A1").Offset(0,3)` where 3 is the number of columns to offset. This would produce "D1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out, `Tgt.Column = 3` won't work. This is because the `Column` property of the `Range` object is read-only, so you can't set its value, you can only read/get it.

Take a look at [`Range.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.14).aspx).

In your case, it'd be something like:

```
Set Tgt = Range("A1").Offset(0, 2)
```

in order to offset your range called `Tgt` by **0** rows down **2** columns to the right, i.e. in the same row and from column **A** to column **C**, resulting in cell `C1`.

Note that positive parameters to `Range.Offset` offset down (for rows) and to the right (for columns), respectively. Negative parameters will offset in the opposite direction.

Comment: Although your answer is thorough, I think @cronos2546 hit the mark. OP doesn't want to set `Tgt` again but a way to access 3 column through it. Btw, that's just what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

```
Tgt.Offset(0,2)
```

This will move the Tgt Column to C/3